# Enable-Feature powershell-command in object model

Tags: publishing-site, event-receivers, object-model

How to do [`Enable-SPFeature`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607803.aspx) equievalent in object model. I want to enable some features (lists) in my publishing site in event receiver. For example:

```
Enable-SPFeature announcementslist -url URL_OF_SITE
```

How can i activate announcementslist by code in event receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SPWeb** or **SPSite** to activate features on subsite or a certain site collection respectively. Here is an example of SPWeb.

```
        try
        {
           SPWeb oWebSite = SPContext.Current.Web;
           feature = oWebSite.Features[new GUID("94C94CA6-B32F-4da9-A9E3-1F3D343D7ECB")];
           if (feature == null)//if feature is not activated  
           //Activating a feature using Object Model    
           oWebSite.Features.Add(new GUID("94C94CA6-B32F-4da9-A9E3-1F3D343D7ECB");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
```

Comment: oWeb.Features.Add is equal to Enable-SPFeature ? And what to do for activating the feature in site collection scope.

Comment: use `SPSite.Features.Add` to add/activate a Site Collection scope feature, call the Add method and pass it the GUID of the feature. Be warned that it will throw an InvalidOperationException if the feature is already activated.

Comment: Very thanks Falak.. What is the best practice to handle exception. Or can we firstly look if the feature is already activated, before running the code?

Comment: I have updated the code with general exception handling.